# IOS NSString Property always nil in referencing class

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, alassetslibrary

Here's my @interface def;

```
@interface Thumbnail : UIView <NSCoding>{
    NSMutableString *imageCacheKeyBase;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableString  *imageCacheKeyBase;
@end
```

Here's my @implementation:

```
@synthesize imageCacheKeyBase;
```

Then in a method called initWithAsset in the Thumbnail class:

```
self.urlString = [[_asset.defaultRepresentation.url absoluteString] copy];
c  = (char*)[urlString UTF8String];

while (*c != '=') 
    ++c;
++c;

self.imageCacheKeyBase = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s_", c];
```

And, so when the Thumbnail allocing class tries to reference thumbnail.imageCacheKeyBase the stinkin' thing is nil.  I've tried a million different approaches to getting a string variable to stick as a property of thumbnail. I even tried simply self.imageCacheKeyBase = @"dave".  Nuthin'.  I've tried retain and retain retain (I know that's stupid but I was trying anything.  I even tried simply making the property a char *.

I've been researching this all day.

Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere down the line, something is nil.   try NSLogging the values of each object or data type.

```
NSLog(@"My first string is %@, the char is %s, the final string is %@", [_asset.defaultRepresentation.url absoluteString], c, self.imageCacheKeyBase);
```

Comment: Well,  last I checked, a c string IS a char *.  %s and char * have gone together like peanut butter and jelly ever since kernigan and richie dreamed up the c language.  I suppose my post might be a bit misleading, however.  c is declared as char *c;  You mentioned that you saw other issues.  Like what?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to get everything up to and including the `=` in the input URL. I would suggest instead of converting to UTF-8 string (unless you have good reason to do this that you haven't mentioned), you do something like:

```
self.urlString = [[_asset.defaultRepresentation.url absoluteString] copy];

NSRange range = [self.urlString rangeOfString@"="];
if (range.location != NSNotFound)
{
    self.imageCacheKeyBase = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s=", [self.urlString subStringToIndex:range.location];
}
```

I would also declare `imageCacheKeyBase` in the .h like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *imageCacheKeyBase;
```

unless you have a need for it to be mutable. If you do need it to be mutable, then in my snippet above, change the `[NSString stringWithFormat...` to `[NSMutableString stringWithFormat...`. Since you're creating the string in this class, you just need to retain, which is preferable to copy.

Also, you reference `self.urlString` in your code snippet but it's not declared in the `@interface`. Maybe you just intend it to be a temporary local variable while you are generating the imageCacheKeyBase? If so, change the first line in my snippet above to:

```
NSString* urlString = [_asset.defaultRepresentation.url absoluteString];
```

`absoluteString` returns an autorelease string, so no need to release it.